# ggplot area plot: order in which groups are rendered affects visibility

Tags: python, pandas, ggplot2

I have this dataframe:

```
     Hour  ENTRIES_hourly_rainy  ENTRIES_hourly_not_rainy  ENTRIES_hourly_total
0      0               3559751                   7248389              10808140
1      1               1606880                   3361780               4968660
2      2                145719                    282413                428132
3      3                 26804                     54543                 81347
4      4                766333                   1672134               2438467
5      5                379272                    800500               1179772
6      6                 59030                    123764                182794
7      7                140758                    242930                383688
8      8               1950224                   3544500               5494724
9      9               3806660                   7234291              11040951
10    10                477959                    837528               1315487
11    11                235289                    410994                646283
12    12               7787028                  15026342              22813370
13    13               3145361                   6265131               9410492
14    14                388437                    776277               1164714
15    15                149688                    297624                447312
16    16               5735102                  11601840              17336942
17    17               4250723                   8442271              12692994
18    18                564774                   1123973               1688747
19    19                290350                    544482                834832
20    20               8302496                  16203000              24505496
21    21               4452747                   8668253              13121000
22    22                418217                    784093               1202310
23    23                115005                    230668                345673
```

I'm using ggplot to display the different columns on the y-axis, and the Hour as a x-axis.
The problem is that the values of the first column are hidden:

```
print ggplot(aes(x='Hour',ymin=0,ymax='value',fill='variable'),data = entriesPerHourPerRain) +
 geom_area()+theme_matplotlib()
```

[image]

I could use alpha in order to see them:

```
   print ggplot(aes(x='Hour',ymin=0,ymax='value',fill='variable'),data = entriesPerHourPerRain) +

 geom_area(alpha=0.6)+theme_matplotlib()
```

[image]

But I would prefer not to use alpha, and having the three areas visible.
I tried to change the "order" of the columns (ENTRIES_hourly_total, ENTRIES_hourly_not_rainy, ENTRIES_hourly_rainy), but it doesn't seem to change.

Does anyone know how to solve this? Thank you!

**-------------------Update:-----------------------**

Following the suggestions below, I tried to inverse the order of the variable (after melting).
I have grouped the hours in 6 groups (now you see them grouped in the column HourGroupIndex)

This is the standard case with [ENTRIES_hourly_rainy,ENTRIES_hourly_not_rainy,ENTRIES_hourly_total]
    entriesPerHourPerRain = pandas.melt(entriesPerHourPerRain,id_vars=['HourGroupIndex'])

```
    HourGroupIndex                  variable     value
0                0      ENTRIES_hourly_rainy   5339154
1                1      ENTRIES_hourly_rainy   1345393
2                2      ENTRIES_hourly_rainy   6470132
3                3      ENTRIES_hourly_rainy  11470514
4                4      ENTRIES_hourly_rainy  10840949
5                5      ENTRIES_hourly_rainy  13288465
6                0  ENTRIES_hourly_not_rainy  10947125
7                1  ENTRIES_hourly_not_rainy   2839328
8                2  ENTRIES_hourly_not_rainy  12027313
9                3  ENTRIES_hourly_not_rainy  22365374
10               4  ENTRIES_hourly_not_rainy  21712566
11               5  ENTRIES_hourly_not_rainy  25886014
12               0      ENTRIES_hourly_total  16286279
13               1      ENTRIES_hourly_total   4184721
14               2      ENTRIES_hourly_total  18497445
15               3      ENTRIES_hourly_total  33835888
16               4      ENTRIES_hourly_total  32553515
17               5      ENTRIES_hourly_total  39174479
```

This is the inveresed case with [ENTRIES_hourly_total,ENTRIES_hourly_rainy,ENTRIES_hourly_not_rainy]:

```
custom_dict= {'ENTRIES_hourly_rainy':3, 'ENTRIES_hourly_not_rainy':2, 'ENTRIES_hourly_total':1}  
entriesPerHourPerRain['rank'] = entriesPerHourPerRain['variable'].map(custom_dict)    
entriesPerHourPerRain.sort(columns=['rank','HourGroupIndex'],inplace=True)
del entriesPerHourPerRain['rank']
entriesPerHourPerRain=entriesPerHourPerRain.reset_index()
del entriesPerHourPerRain['index']

    HourGroupIndex                  variable     value
0                0      ENTRIES_hourly_total  16286279
1                1      ENTRIES_hourly_total   4184721
2                2      ENTRIES_hourly_total  18497445
3                3      ENTRIES_hourly_total  33835888
4                4      ENTRIES_hourly_total  32553515
5                5      ENTRIES_hourly_total  39174479
6                0  ENTRIES_hourly_not_rainy  10947125
7                1  ENTRIES_hourly_not_rainy   2839328
8                2  ENTRIES_hourly_not_rainy  12027313
9                3  ENTRIES_hourly_not_rainy  22365374
10               4  ENTRIES_hourly_not_rainy  21712566
11               5  ENTRIES_hourly_not_rainy  25886014
12               0      ENTRIES_hourly_rainy   5339154
13               1      ENTRIES_hourly_rainy   1345393
14               2      ENTRIES_hourly_rainy   6470132
15               3      ENTRIES_hourly_rainy  11470514
16               4      ENTRIES_hourly_rainy  10840949
17               5      ENTRIES_hourly_rainy  13288465
```

But I still have the same plot in both cases

```
print  ggplot(aes(x='HourGroupIndex',ymin=0,ymax='value',fill='variable'),data = entriesPerHourPerRain) + geom_area(alpha=0.6,position='dodge')+scale_x_continuous(breaks = range(0,6), labels=['0-3','1-7','2-11','3-15','4-19','5-23'])+theme_matplotlib()
```

It seems that the order doesn't change much.

[image]

Comment: Did you melt your data.frame before plotting? The sample data you posted above does not seem to match up to what's in `entriesPerHourPerRain` given the names of the `aes` mappings. Nor does it make much sense that you are using literal string values in your `aes()` calls. You typically use either symbols or you use strings with `aes_string`. Are you sure this is representative of the data and code you are actually running?

Comment: I assume you have melted the original dataframe? Does re-ordering the factor levels of variable help? e.g. something like `variable = factor(variable,levels(variable)[c("ENTRIES_hourly_total", "ENTRIES_hourly_not_rainy", "ENTRIES_hourly_rainy"))])`

Comment: Yes sorry I forgot to add the melt:
`entriesPerHourPerRain = pandas.melt(entriesPerHourPerRain,id_vars=['Hour'])`

@AdamKimberley I'm not really familiar with that, does it simply change the "order" of the columns? I've tried that "manually" but it doesn't seem to change. Anyway, I'll give it a try with your code

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like Python, not R, so this might not be helpful. I think the ggplot defaults are different in Python. (You did tag the question R though.)

In R:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
gg <- melt(entriesPerHourPerRain, id="Hour")
ggplot(gg, aes(x=Hour,y=value,fill=variable)) +
  geom_area(position="dodge")
```

produces this:

[image]

Whereas this code:

```
gg$variable <- factor(gg$variable, levels=rev(levels(gg$variable)))
ggplot(gg, aes(x=Hour,y=value,fill=variable)) +
  geom_area(position="dodge")
```

produces this:
[image]

So `variable` is a factor and the original levels are set in the order of the columns (_rainy, _not_rainy, _total). When plotted this way the last column's values obscure the other two. The line:

```
gg$variable <- factor(gg$variable, levels=rev(levels(gg$variable)))
```

reverses the order of the factor levels, so now _rainy is plotted last.

Note the use of `position="dodge"`. The default in `geom_area(...)` [in R] is "stacked", wherein the y values will be additive (so the y-values for _total will be _rainy + _not_rainy + _total). You don't seem to want this.

Comment: @jihoward thank you for your solution. Please have a look at my update! Sorry for tagging the question with R, I assumed that ggplot for python was quite similar